# 136 is not valid CURL hanlder--PHP

Tags: php

this are the options i have set in CURL.

```
      curl_setopt($curlHandler[$j]->curl, CURLOPT_URL,$arr[$j]->URL);
      curl_setopt($curlHandler[$j]->curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
      curl_setopt($curlHandler[$j]->curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
      curl_setopt($curlHandler[$j]->curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
      curl_setopt($curlHandler[$j]->curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
      curl_setopt($curlHandler[$j]->curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
      curl_setopt($curlHandler[$j]->curl,10);
```

When i execute PHP curl. curl_getinfo return following array.

```
Array
(
    [url] => http://davidchartier.com/post/395028979/replies
    [content_type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
    [http_code] => 404
    [header_size] => 669
    [request_size] => 224
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 1
    [total_time] => 1.939753
    [namelookup_time] => 0.079254
    [connect_time] => 0.099593
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.099693
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 21201
    [speed_download] => 10929
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => 255
    [upload_content_length] => 0
    [starttransfer_time] => 1.759269
    [redirect_time] => 0.129832
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [redirect_url] => 
)


<b>Warning</b>:  (null)(): 136 is not a valid cURL handle resource in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
<br />
```

please help me.any kind of help is appreciated.